# Is my data random according to clustering?

Tags: clustering

I have a data from 2 cohorts. Each cohort can be divided into 2 identical groups (actually I have ~10 old and ~10 young people in each cohort). I made a hierarchical clustering of the whole dataset of ~40 people.

Is there a way to say that the clustering is not random according to the cohorts? (Picture is attached). The dataset depicted on the plot can be divided approximately in the middle and data from 1st group (Old) from both cohort will be on the left and data from 2nd group (Young) will be on the right so the problem can be simplified and divided into 2 subproblems, with stratification into 2 groups.

Q: Having a hierarchical clustering and 1 trait (0/1), how can I say if clustering was dependent from the trait?

PCA does not show the clear clustering of samples from different cohorts, but the hclustering looks suspicious.

**Q2** (more general): How to measure the strength of batch effect in the dataset?

[image]

Comment: This looks very blurred question in its some phrases and formulations. What is "randomness" here, what is "batch effect"? `Having a hierarchical clustering and 1 trait (0/1), how can I say if clustering was dependent from the trait?` - this I could hardly understand.

Comment: 'randomness' = there is no clustering structure (so you can not dissect you hclust into two parts, 1 from 1 group, 2nd - from another). Batch = observed/unobserved factor, in this case = Cohort (first or second), does it influence the data, can be see clustering of data from cohorts together. Trait = Cohort, again. If we have 100 datapoints from 2 cohorts, and hclust will show 2 distinct clusters of 50 and 50 and the match with cluster and cohort number will be perfect - I would say it is not random. I would just like to formalize it.

Comment: Actually the dendrogram you show looks *very* random to me... at most I'd agree that the first object is an outlier.

Answer (score 1):

Hierarchical clustering is descriptive method. Try to use one of ANOVA tests to test hypothesis that your data distributed across groups non-randomly

Comment: What do you mean under 'batch effect'?

Comment: Which test from ANOVA framework can show that the data is distributed non-randomly in case their means/variances match?

Comment: I know about Rand index, can it be applied for the particular problem?

Comment: Sorry, i could not understand something. Let's say you have 2 groups X1 and X2 both contains N observations. Possible observations are 1 or 0.  In these case if these groups have same mean, they will have same median, variance and whatever you wish. To test such non-normal data i like numerical approach very well described [here](https://www.ecoevol.ufg.br/adrimelo/div/Anderson-2001-AustEcol_non-parametric_manova.pdf).

Comment: Thanks, I will read the paper...usually I used ANOVA to show the difference in means, but the paper describe smth else

Answer (score 1):

You **cannot use clustering for disproving the existence of patterns**.

Because doing clustering right is hard. There is no guarantee that you find everything, because you may simply have done bad preprocessing.

For example, let's generate data like this: draw from two normal distributions, either $N(0, 0.1)$ or $N(0.2, 0.1)$. Shuffle the union of these two sets. Most of the time, we will manage to cluster this data. Now lets do *one* mistake: include an unique ID column. Add a column to the (shuffled!) data that is simply 1...n and this will completely ruin the clustering.

So clustering is easy to screw up.

If you don't find anything, you do not know whether this is because of A) bad preprocessing (common), B) bad parameters (common), C) bad implementation (common, there are many bugs), D) there are really no clusters in the data (not too common, but often the clusters are not very interesting; for example 99.9%of data may be one cluster).

Comment: Thanks, I agree, but the question is 'what if the clustering was done in a right way'? Sometimes we can say that clustering is not random "by eye", a lot of papers are based on such observations (like "we clearly see that our data cluster into 3 groups"), I just wander if there is a formal way to say that the clustering makes sense and is not because of random.